# Single Page Application: How to unmount app in Vue.js 3 Composition API when enter/reload the app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vue-router

Webpack server is showing the following warning in browser console :

> [Vue warn]: There is already an app instance mounted on the host container.
> If you want to mount another app on the same host container, you need to unmount the
> previous app by calling `app.unmount()` first.

So, I'm facing an issue with proper use of:

```js
app.unmount()
```

**main.js**

```js
// Import methods and component.
import { createApp} from 'vue';
import router from './router';
import App from './App.vue';

// Create vue App.
const app = createApp(App);

// Install the required instances like plugin, component and directive.
app.use(router);

// Mount 'app' const (App.vue) as root component.
app.mount('#app');
```

**App.vue**

```js
<template>

 <div>
    <div id="header">Hello world</div>

    <div id="main">
    
        <router-view name="default" v-slot="{ Component, route }">

          <div v-if="errMsg" class="container mt-3">
            <h2 class="text-center">
              {{ errMsg }}
            </h2>
          </div>

          <div v-else>
            <component :is="Component"
                       :key="route.meta.usePathKey ? route.path : undefined">

            </component>
          </div>
    
        </router-view>
    
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import {ref, onErrorCaptured} from 'vue';

export default {
  name: "App",
}
</script>

<script setup>

// constants, functions and life-cycle hooks
const errMsg = ref(null);

onErrorCaptured(() => {
  errMsg.value = "Something went wrong!";
});

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**Note**

1-  I can't use `app.unmount()` in `main.js` directly and

2- can't use Vue life-cycle hooks like `onUnmounted()` because should only use inside setup() script.

3- can't unmount `app` from `App.vue` (nonsense).

Comment: It's unclear what's the problem exactly. 1-2-3 - why is that? But primarily it looks like XY problem. If you try to use app.unmount just because of a message in console, then your assumption is wrong, it's likely your setup to blame and it needs to be fixed

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanx for your suggestion, but there is no problem in the code, please take a look on the answer.

Comment: As I said, you seem to try to solve a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place. It's specific to your setup, so it makes sense to resolve the problem with the setup rather than trying to quick fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, I should see if `app` (App.vue) is already mount, it's useful:

1- When refresh the page, so you don't need to mount another `app` instance as Webpack server suggest in the warning.

2- Will prevent trigger the methods these defined in `App.vue` `<script setup>` twice (one for update life-cycle of component and second when re-mount the component again, which happens when refresh the page).

**main.js**

```js
// Import methods and component.
import { createApp} from 'vue';
import router from './router';
import App from './App.vue';


let app = "";
let containerSelector = "#app";

// check if app has been mounted already
const mountPoint = document.querySelector(containerSelector);

if (mountPoint && mountPoint.__vue_app__ !== undefined) {

    // Set the existing mount point to 'app'.
    app = mountPoint.__vue_app__._instance.proxy;
}
else {

    // create a new app instance
    app = createApp(App);
    
    // Install the required instances like plugin, component and directive.
    app.use(router);

    // Mount 'app' (App.vue) as root component.
    app.mount(containerSelector);
}
```

If you don't want to use the existing `app` instance, you can change the code by use `app.unmount()` inside `if{}` block and remove `else{}` block, then outside the condition block plug in your components, stores..etc to the new created `app` instance and mount it at the end.